# It seems that mongoDB compression does not work properly

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

Nginx + php-fpm + mongoDB(+mongodb php-lib)

trying to compare the compression rate of mongoDB
but, the results are not as expected.
Here are my experiments.

```
/etc/mongod.conf  

# mongod.conf  //default setting

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
#operationProfiling:
#replication:
#sharding:
## Enterprise-Only Options:
#auditLog:
#snmp:
```

> Setting compression when creating collection in mongoDB shell
>
> mongoDB shell> db.createCollection( "test",{storageEngine:{wiredTiger:{configString:'block_compressor=none, prefix_compression=false'}}})
>
> The compression options are set to 6 in total
>
> block_compressor = none or snappy or zlib // prefix_compression = false or true
>
> When checked with db.printCollectionStats(), the options were applied correctly.

insert data size is 100KB * 100000 = about 9GB.

but db.test.storageSize() result.

block_compression none = 10653536256 (byte)

block_compression snappy = 10653405184 (byte)

block_compression zlib = 6690177024 (byte)

zlib  is about 40% compressed compared to none.
but, none and snappy are not different.

(prefix_compress is also unchanged.)

What settings should I add?

+UPDATE

snappy+false

```
"compression" : {
            "compressed pages read" : 0,
            "compressed pages written" : 0,
            "page written failed to compress" : 100007,
            "page written was too small to compress" : 1025
       }
```

zlib+false

```
"compression" : {
            "compressed pages read" : 0,
            "compressed pages written" : 98881,
            "page written failed to compress" : 0,
            "page written was too small to compress" : 924
       }
```

what is "page written failed to compress" mean?
What is the solution?

+update2

used mongoDB server version: 4.0.9

```
insert data document

$result = $collection->insertOne( ['num'=> (int)$i , 
                                    'title' => "$i", 
                                    'main' => "$i", 
                                    'img' => "$t",
                                    'user'=>"$users", 
                                    'like'=> 0,
                                    'time'=> "$date" ] );

---Variable Description---
$i = 1 ~ 100,000 (Increment by 1)
$t = 100KB(102400byt) random string 
$users =  (Random 10 characters in 12134567890abcdefghij)
$data =  Real-time server date (ex = 2019:05:18 xx.xx.xx)

index 
db.test.createIndex( { "num":1 } )
db.test.createIndex( { "title":1 } )
db.test.createIndex( { "user":1 } )
db.test.createIndex( { "like":1 } )
db.test.createIndex( { "time":1 } )
```

collection stats is too long so I will put only two.

snappy+false

> "creationString" : "access_pattern_hint=none,allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1),assert=(commit_timestamp=none,read_timestamp=none),block_allocation=best,**block_compressor=snappy**,cache_resident=false,checksum=on,colgroups=,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,encryption=(keyid=,name=),exclusive=false,extractor=,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,ignore_in_memory_cache_size=false,immutable=false,internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=true,internal_page_max=4KB,key_format=q,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=32KB,leaf_value_max=64MB,log=(enabled=true),lsm=(auto_throttle=true,bloom=true,bloom_bit_count=16,bloom_config=,bloom_hash_count=8,bloom_oldest=false,chunk_count_limit=0,chunk_max=5GB,chunk_size=10MB,merge_custom=(prefix=,start_generation=0,suffix=),merge_max=15,merge_min=0),memory_page_image_max=0,memory_page_max=10m,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,**prefix_compression=false**,prefix_compression_min=4,source=,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,type=file,value_format=u",

snappy+true

> "creationString" : "access_pattern_hint=none,allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1),assert=(commit_timestamp=none,read_timestamp=none),block_allocation=best,**block_compressor=snappy**,cache_resident=false,checksum=on,colgroups=,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,encryption=(keyid=,name=),exclusive=false,extractor=,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,ignore_in_memory_cache_size=false,immutable=false,internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=true,internal_page_max=4KB,key_format=q,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=32KB,leaf_value_max=64MB,log=(enabled=true),lsm=(auto_throttle=true,bloom=true,bloom_bit_count=16,bloom_config=,bloom_hash_count=8,bloom_oldest=false,chunk_count_limit=0,chunk_max=5GB,chunk_size=10MB,merge_custom=(prefix=,start_generation=0,suffix=),merge_max=15,merge_min=0),memory_page_image_max=0,memory_page_max=10m,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,**prefix_compression=true**,prefix_compression_min=4,source=,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,type=file,value_format=u",

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: How are you generating your test documents?  Are you using the same test data for comparison? The "page written failed to compress" metric suggests that your data was not compressible so was stored uncompressed. This typically happens if your data is already compressed (for example, image or video files). Can you also check your collection compression options are set as expected using  `db.collectionname.stats().wiredTiger.creationString`? Lastly, what specific version of MongoDB server are you using?

Comment: @Stennie i have updated the answer to your question.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: @Neil Lunn - Sorry I did not know. I'll delete it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that jumps out is that you use `allocation_size=4KB`. With this allocation size, your disk blocks are too small to be compressed, so they won't be compressed. Increase `allocation_size` to make compression kick in.